# PHP MySQL order by first column, if second NULL

Tags: mysql

I have table:

```
id  |  post_date  |  bumped_post_date
1   |    date     |       NULL
2   |    date     |       date2
```

Ok, I know how to order by `post_date`, but I wan't to order by `post_date` only when `bumped_post_date` is **NULL**.

When `bumped_post_date` is not NULL, then order by it, not by post_date ( But if NULL, then order by post_date ). Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: you can probably use MySQL's CASE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: or a `WHERE` clause with `AND|OR` with a subquery. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use  a case when

```
select * from my_table 
order by case when  bumped_post_date is null 
            then post_date else bumped_post_date end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY COALESCE( bumped_post_date, post_date )
```

Coalesce() function returns the first non-null argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY`:

```
select *
from your_table
order by case 
        when bumped_post_date is not null
            then bumped_post_date
        else post_date
        end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much !